# Techniques for digital superluminal communication

Tags: communication, physics, radio-communication

Considering photons only travel at the speed of light (and cannot travel faster), our main technique of digital communication (at least I believe, but I could be wrong) is off the table.

What techniques are being investigated for digital superluminal communication?  Would these techniques be applicable to space missions where communication lag is significant?

Comment: Faster than light communication violates causality.  You can use it to send a message back in time.  It is therefore quite unlikely to be possible.

Comment: different but related: [Is Quantum Entanglement technology possible for interplanetary communication in future to achieve low real-time latency?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32371/12102) and same answer (no).

Answer (score 10):

Currently, no techniques *exist* to send information faster than the speed of light. However, there are some theories:

- Group velocity > c experiments
- Evanescent wave coupling
- Tachyons
- Quantum nonlocality

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_communication) on the subject:

> According to the currently accepted theory, three of those four phenomena **do not produce superluminal communication**, even though they may give that appearance under some conditions. The third, tachyons, **arguably do not exist as their existence is hypothetical**; even if their existence were to be proven, attempts to quantize them **appear to indicate that they may not be used** for superluminal communication, because experiments to produce or absorb tachyons **cannot be fully controlled**.

If wormholes are possible, they *could* be used to transmit information:

> **If wormholes are possible**, then ordinary subluminal methods of communication **could be sent through them to achieve superluminal transmission speeds**. Considering the immense energy that current theories suggest would be required to open a wormhole large enough to pass spacecraft through it may be that only **atomic-scale wormholes would be practical** to build, **limiting their use solely to information transmission**.

There is some *small* possibility that quantum entanglement would achieve the desired effect:

> some argue that superluminal communication **could be achieved via quantum entanglement** using other methods that **don't rely on cloning a quantum system**. One suggested method would use an **ensemble of entangled particles to transmit information**, similar to a type of quantum eraser experiments. As the quantum eraser experiments **rely on a classical, subluminal channel** for coincidence detection, it is **unclear whether superluminal communication would be possible** by this method. Physicist John G. Cramer at the University of Washington is **attempting to replicate one of these experiments** and demonstrate whether or not it can produce superluminal communication.

Therefore, we **currently** don't have any means of superluminal communications, but there are theories. If we can create a wormhole (very unlikely anytime soon), then it would be *possible...*